# Material-UI - How to pass custom props to a custom TreeItem?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I need to pass an argument `category` to `CustomTreeItem` which is `TreeItemContent`.
Doc: https://mui.com/ru/api/tree-item/

```
import TreeItem, {
  TreeItemProps,
  useTreeItem,
  TreeItemContentProps,
} from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';

interface CatProps {
  name: string,
  id: string,
}

interface CatItemContentProps extends TreeItemContentProps {
  category: CatProps,
}

const CustomContent = React.forwardRef(function CustomContent(
    props: CatItemContentProps,
    ref,
  ) {
    const { category } = props;
    console.log(category); // undefined

  return <></>;
  }
);


interface CatItemProps extends TreeItemProps {
  category: CatProps,
}

const CustomTreeItem = (props: CatItemProps) => {
  return (
    <TreeItem ContentComponent={CustomContent} {...props} />
  );
};
```

How can I do it?

**Сlarifications after the first answer**

The new code is:

```
const CustomContent = React.forwardRef(function CustomContent(
  props: TreeItemContentProps,
  ref
) {
  return (
    <div ref={ref as React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>}>
      {props.label} {props.myProps}
    </div>
  );
});

const CustomTreeItem = (props: TreeItemProps) => {
  return <TreeItem ContentComponent={CustomContent} {...props} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TreeView>
      <CustomTreeItem
        nodeId="1"
        label="Applications"
        ContentProps={{
          myProps: "my props"
        }}
      ></CustomTreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

I've made it in codesandbox and it works fine:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-volhard-km9xf?file=/src/App.tsx

But it my code I have a new error:

```
Type '{ myProps: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myProps' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>'
```

Google gives me the same problem from another person:
https://issueexplorer.com/issue/mui-org/material-ui/28668

Availiable attributes for this type are:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1349b640d4d07f40aa7c1c6931f18e3fbf667f3a/types/react/index.d.ts#L1743

How can I pass my custom props to ContentProps?

Comment: I didn't get notified when you edited the question, if you want to ask follow up questions, you can comment in my answer, that way your messages can show up in my inbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`ContentProps`](https://mui.com/api/tree-item/#:%7E:text=hold%20a%20ref.-,ContentProps,-object) props, it will be merged with the original `TreeItemContentProps`

```
<CustomTreeItem
  nodeId="1"
  label="Applications"
  ContentProps={{
    myProps: "my props",
  }}
>
```

```
const CustomContent = React.forwardRef(function CustomContent(
  props: TreeItemContentProps,
  ref
) {
  console.log(props.myProps); // "my props"
```

**EDIT:** For typescript users, you also need to augment the prop interface of `TreeItemContent` to remove the error:

```
declare module "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem" {
  interface TreeItemContentProps {
    myProps: string;
  }
}
```

The `ContentProps` itself can't be augmented, this is a shortcoming from the MUI API, a workaround is simply ignore it:

```
ContentProps={
  {
    myProps: "my props"
  } as any
}
```

Comment: I've made it in codesandbox and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-volhard-km9xf?file=/src/App.tsx.

But it my code in IDE VS I have a new error:
`Type '{ myProps: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myProps' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>'`

Availiable attributes for this type are:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1349b640d4d07f40aa7c1c6931f18e3fbf667f3a/types/react/index.d.ts#L1743

How can I pass my custom props to ContentProps?

Comment: @user3713526 You're missing the last 2 code snippets in my answer: `{ myProps: "my props" } as any`. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-tdd-mzcl6?file=/src/App.tsx) codesandbox.

Answer (score 2):

As per current document follow these steps

I found the way as mentioned on following document

Code Ref: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/512896973499adbbda057e7f3685d1b23cc02de9/docs/src/components/productX/XTreeViewDemo.tsx

Step1
Add custom property along TreeItemContentProps on custom component create

```
 const CustomContentChildContent = React.forwardRef(function CustomContent(
        props: TreeItemContentProps & { myCustomData?: string },
        ref,
    )
```

Step2
Add custom property to with TreeItemProps

```
const CustomTreeItemChild = (
  props: TreeItemProps & {
    ContentProps?: { myCustomData?: string };
  },
) => <StyledTreeItem ContentComponent={CustomContentChildContent} {...props} />;
```

Step3

Add property in the component you are calling

```
<CustomTreeItemChild nodeId="3" label={item.name} ContentProps={{ myCustomData: 'anything-i-can-pass' }} />
```